# `<dead-grave> is undefined`

Tags: key-bindings, latex, debugging

for a few month, I use Emacs for Latex, and I am French.

today (for the first time) when I use `` C-c ` `` to see my errors, Emacs answers

`<dead-grave> is undefined`

I try to add in my .emacs

``` (global-set-key (kbd "<dead-grave>") "``") ```  (only one dead grave

And I also try `(require 'iso-transl)`

It doesn't work !

What can I do ? thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

First what you can do is set an alias for `emacs` in you `~/.bashrc` like so:

```
alias emacs="env XMODIFIERS= emacs"
```

This will fix it when you start emacs, but it won't fix it if you start it from clicking on a file, so what you can do if you have Ubuntu is:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/emacs25.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/emacs25.desktop
```

Then edit your new `emacs25.desktop` file to start a script instead of the actual emacs application:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=GNU Emacs 25 (GUI)
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=GNU Emacs is an extensible, customizable text editor - and more
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
TryExec=/home/you/.local/share/applications/emacs.sh
Exec=/home/you/.local/share/applications/emacs.sh %F
Icon=emacs25
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;Development;TextEditor;
StartupWMClass=Emacs
Keywords=Text;Editor;
```

And finally you create a script in the same folder `emacs.sh` to start emacs with your custom parameters:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
env XMODIFIERS= emacs "$@"
```

It might say that the shortcut isn't trusted, that can be fixed by `chmod +x emacs25.desktop` and don't forget to `chmod +x emacs.sh` also!

Hope this helps ;)